How to migrate to SDK34 in flutter?
I tried to upgrade SDK from 33 to 34 now with flutter.
So, In the process, I realized that it needed to upgrade gradle from 7.x.x to 8.x.
However, There are many errors like ,

'AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found' or Error: Gradle
build failed to produce an .apk file.

It's likely that this file was generated under /Users/ydlee/Flutter/sample/build, but the tool couldn't find it.
I have not solved for a month about this.
First, I want to know if the latest version of flutter can run with gradle 8.x.
Second, If there is the successful case with gradle 8.x, Please let me know AGP version and Gradle version and Kotlin version you set.
Please...
I tried to upgrade from gradle 8.0 to 8.7 and set fitting AGP version but All errors occurred alternatively. I just want to get no error when I use flutter run.

If you are using Flutter 3.24.0 it is possible that's the issue.
It has been reported many times.
